# Sails Js: Inserting(Create) Multiple objects in A table(model) skipping existing Rows(Objects)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

**How can i insert an arraya of objects in a table while skipping existing rows.**
I have a model with definition.

```
//Test.js
module.exports={
  tableName:'test',
  connection: 'mysqlServer',
  attributes:{
    id:{
      type:'integer',
      primaryKey:true
    },
    name:{
      type:'string'
    }
  }
};
```

in test table i already have

```
-----------------
|id       name  |
-----------------
|1        AB1   |
|2        AB2   |
-----------------

var arrData=[
  {3,'AB3'},
  {4,'AB4'},
  {2,'AB2'},  //skip this object proceeding to next
  {5,'AB5'},
  {6,'AB6'},
  {7,'AB7'}
]
```

i want to push this arrData to my test table but performing

```
Test.create(arrData).exec(function(err,rows){
    if(err)
      throw err;
    else
      console.log(rows)
})
```

will stop whenever it finds {2,'AB2'} but i want to skip this object and proceed to push rest of the objects and store the id of the object which was found existing in the table to indicate.

**How can i achieve my objective**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyhow i figured it out.
The solutions is using async:

```
var async=require('async');
var arrData=[
  {3,'AB3'},
  {4,'AB4'},
  {2,'AB2'},  //skip this object proceeding to next
  {5,'AB5'},
  {6,'AB6'},
  {7,'AB7'}
]
var arrLen=arrData.length,i=0;
var errData=[];
async.whilst(
  function(){
    return i<arrLen;
  },function(callback){
    Test.create(arrData[i]).exec(function(err,data){
      if(err){
        errData.push(arrData[i]);
      }
      callback(null,i++);
    });
  },function(err,n){
    console.log(errData);//These are the data where error encountered!!!
  });
```

***If anyone have other solution please share....***